# Integrate single sign on using spring security oauth

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on an application guarding few REST APIs with Spring Security OAuth2.The authentication works fine.Now i want to implement the single sign on feature for each account.That once a user successfully login using his credential from one device then its not possible to login the same use user from some other device.That is at a time only one login is allowed for a user.If he wants to login in another device he should logout from the already login device.How to do this in spring security oauth.Below is my codes.

spring-security.xml :

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">


          <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 

                <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" method="POST" />
                <anonymous enabled="false" />
                <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
                <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
                <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
          </http>

          <http pattern="/protected/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
                <anonymous enabled="false" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" method="GET" access="ROLE_APP" />
                <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
                <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
                <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
          </http>

          <http pattern="/logout" create-session="never" 
                entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
                <anonymous enabled="false" />
                <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
                <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"   />
                <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
                <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
          </http>

          <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.example.myproject.security.LogoutImpl" >
                <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore"></property>
          </bean>

          <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
                <property name="exceptionTranslator" ref="myExceptionTranslator"></property>
          </bean>

      <bean id="myExceptionTranslator"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator">
          </bean>

          <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
                <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
                <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
          </bean>

          <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
          </bean>

          <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
          </bean>

          <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
                <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
          </authentication-manager>

          <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
                <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
          </bean>

          <bean id="clientDetails" class="com.example.myproject.service.ClientService"/>

          <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager" 
                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
                <authentication-provider  user-service-ref="userService">
                </authentication-provider>
          </authentication-manager>

          <bean id="userService"
                class="com.example.myproject.service.UserService">
          </bean>

          <oauth:authorization-server
                client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
                <oauth:authorization-code />
                <oauth:implicit/>
                <oauth:refresh-token/>
                <oauth:client-credentials />
                <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
          </oauth:authorization-server>

          <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

          <!-- <bean id="tokenStore"
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" /> -->

          <bean id="tokenStore"
              class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" >
                <property name="authenticationKeyGenerator">
                      <bean class="com.example.myproject.service.UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator" />
                </property> 
         </bean>

          <bean id="tokenServices" 
                class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
                <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
                <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
                <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"></property>
                <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
                <property name="tokenEnhancer"><bean class="com.example.myproject.service.CustomTokenEnhancer" /></property>
          </bean>

          <sec:global-method-security
                pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
                <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
                      http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
                <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
          </sec:global-method-security>

          <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
          <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    </beans>
```

ClientService.java :

```
            @Component
    public class ClientService implements ClientDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private OauthRepository oauthRepository;

        @Override
        public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String s) throws ClientRegistrationException{
            BaseClientDetails clientDetails = oauthRepository.getByClientId(s);
                  return clientDetails;

        }
    }
```

UserService.java :

```
            @Component
    public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private OauthRepository oauthRepository;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
          UserDetails user = oauthRepository.getByUsername(s);
                  return user;

        }
    }
```

OauthRepository.java :

```
            @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class OauthRepository {

          @Autowired
          private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

          @Autowired
          private InMemoryTokenStore tokenStore;

          private org.hibernate.Session getCurrentSession(){
                return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          }



        public UserDetails getByUsername(String username) {

                MyUser user=new MyUser();
                user.setUserName(username);
                Query query=getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM User WHERE userName=:usrName");
                query.setParameter("usrName", username);
                List<SiUser> getUser=query.list();

                User act=getUser.get(0);
                user.setPassword(act.getPassword());
                user.setUserId(act.getUserId());
                user.setAuthorities(getAuthorities(act.getUserId()));

                return user;
        }

        public BaseClientDetails getByClientId(String clientId) {
          System.out.println(" *** OauthRepository.getByClientId "+clientId);

          Query query=getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM OauthClientDetails WHERE clientId=:clientId");
                query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
                List<OauthClientDetails> getClient=query.list();

                OauthClientDetails oauthClient=getClient.get(0);
                BaseClientDetails details = new BaseClientDetails();
                details.setClientId(oauthClient.getClientId());
                List<String> grantTypesList = Arrays.asList(oauthClient.getAuthorizedGrantTypes().split(","));
                details.setAuthorizedGrantTypes(grantTypesList); 
                details.setClientSecret(oauthClient.getClientSecret());

            return details;


        }

    /**
     * Retrieves a collection of {@link GrantedAuthority} based on a numerical role
     * @param role the numerical role
     * @return a collection of {@link GrantedAuthority
     */
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
          List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
          return authList;
    }
    /**
     * Converts a numerical role to an equivalent list of roles
     * @param role the numerical role
     * @return list of roles as as a list of {@link String}
     */
    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {
          List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

          Query query=getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM UserRole WHERE userID=:userId");
          query.setParameter("userId", role);
          List<SiUserRole> getUser=query.list();

          UserRole actRole=getUser.get(0);
          roles.add(actRole.getRole());
          return roles;
    }
    /**
     * Wraps {@link String} roles to {@link SimpleGrantedAuthority} objects
     * @param roles {@link String} of roles
     * @return list of granted authorities
     */
    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
          List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
          for (String role : roles) {
                authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role));
          }
          return authorities;
    }


    }
```

servlet-context.xml :

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
          <!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
          <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myproject" />
          <mvc:annotation-driven />

          <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">      

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
         <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
          </bean>      

          <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase"/>
        <property name="username" value="username"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
      </bean>

      <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
      <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
          <array>
            <value>com.example.myproject</value>
          </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
          </value>
        </property>
      </bean>
      <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
      <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
      </bean>

      <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    </beans>
```